# score presence or abscence matrix in r

Tags: r, loops, dataset

Here is my data:

```
   name = c(letters[1:10], letters[1:10])
    Yr <- rep(1:2, each = length (name))
    P1 = c(NA, NA,NA, NA, "a", "a", "a", "d", "d", "d", NA, NA,NA,
    NA, "a", "a", "a", "d", "d", "d")
    P2 =  c(NA, NA,NA, NA, "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
    NA, NA,NA, NA, "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c")
    myd <- data.frame (Yr, name, P1, P2)
```

For all unique value except  in P1 and P2, I would like to create new variables named a and b, then score their presence or absence in P1 and P2 column. Just like the following:

```
Yr   name   P1     P2      a     b    c    d
1    a      <NA>   <NA>    NA    NA   NA   NA
1    b      <NA>   <NA>    NA    NA   NA   NA
1    c      <NA>   <NA>    NA    NA   NA   NA
1    d      <NA>   <NA>    NA    NA   NA   NA
1    e      a      b       1     1    0    0
1    f      a      b       1     1    0    0
1    g      a      b       1     1    0    0
1    h      d      b       0     1    0    1
1    i      d      b       0     1    0    1
1    j      d      c       0     0    1    1
```

(1) **new columns** - The new columns are unique value in P1 and P2 column (except missing value)

(2) **Values for new columns** - For example, for case of "a" name (subject) both P1 and P2 is  so NA.
              for case of "e", name P1 is "a", and P2 is  "b", so "a" and "b", will get 1, everything else is 0, similarly based on presence of P1 or P2, the columns a, b, c,d are scored.

The full expected output:

```
Yr  name P1     P2     a    b   c   d
1   a   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
1   b   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
1   c   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
1   d   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
1   e   a   b   1   1   0   0
1   f   a   b   1   1   0   0
1   g   a   b   1   1   0   0
1   h   d   b   0   1   0   1
1   i   d   b   0   1   0   1
1   j   d   c   0   0   1   1
1   a   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
1   b   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
1   c   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
1   d   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
1   e   a   b   1   1   0   0
1   f   a   b   1   1   0   0
1   g   a   b   1   1   0   0
1   h   d   b   0   1   0   1
1   i   d   b   0   1   0   1
1   j   d   c   0   0   1   1
2   a   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
2   b   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
2   c   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
2   d   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
2   e   a   b   1   1   0   0
2   f   a   b   1   1   0   0
2   g   a   b   1   1   0   0
2   h   d   b   0   1   0   1
2   i   d   b   0   1   0   1
2   j   d   c   0   0   1   1
2   a   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
2   b   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
2   c   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
2   d   <NA>    <NA>    NA  NA  NA  NA
2   e   a   b   1   1   0   0
2   f   a   b   1   1   0   0
2   g   a   b   1   1   0   0
2   h   d   b   0   1   0   1
2   i   d   b   0   1   0   1
2   j   d   c   0   0   1   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newcolname <- with(myd,sort(union(levels(P1),levels(P2))))
newcollist <- with(myd,lapply(newcolname,function(x) as.numeric(P1==x|P2==x)))
names(newcollist) <- newcolname
newcoldf <- data.frame(newcollist)
myd <- cbind(myd,newcoldf)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt using a double `merge` and `model.matrix`:

```
result <- merge(
  merge(myd,model.matrix(~ P1 - 1, data=myd),by="row.names",all.x=TRUE),
  model.matrix(~ P2 - 1, data=myd),
  by.x="Row.names",by.y="row.names",all.x=TRUE
)

# put the data in the 'right' order again and rename the columns
result <- result[order(as.numeric(result$Row.names)),]
names(result)[6:9] <- gsub("P1|P2","",names(result)[6:9])
```

Which gives a final product like this, though the column names are not quite listed in the order specified.

```
> result
   Row.names Yr name   P1   P2  a  d  b  c
1          1  1    a <NA> <NA> NA NA NA NA
12         2  1    b <NA> <NA> NA NA NA NA
23         3  1    c <NA> <NA> NA NA NA NA
34         4  1    d <NA> <NA> NA NA NA NA
36         5  1    e    a    b  1  0  1  0
37         6  1    f    a    b  1  0  1  0
38         7  1    g    a    b  1  0  1  0
39         8  1    h    d    b  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(myd)
dt[, grp := gl(4, 10)]
dt[, list(a = sum(unique(P1) == "a"), 
          b = sum(unique(P1) == "d"), 
          c = sum(unique(P2) == "b"), 
          d = sum(unique(P2) == "c")), 
by=list(grp, Yr, name)]
#     grp Yr name  a  b  c  d
#  1:   1  1    a NA NA NA NA
#  2:   1  1    b NA NA NA NA
#  3:   1  1    c NA NA NA NA
#  4:   1  1    d NA NA NA NA
#  5:   1  1    e  1  0  1  0
#  6:   1  1    f  1  0  1  0
#  7:   1  1    g  1  0  1  0
#  8:   1  1    h  0  1  1  0
#  9:   1  1    i  0  1  1  0
# 10:   1  1    j  0  1  0  1
# 11:   2  1    a NA NA NA NA
# 12:   2  1    b NA NA NA NA
# 13:   2  1    c NA NA NA NA
# 14:   2  1    d NA NA NA NA
# 15:   2  1    e  1  0  1  0
# 16:   2  1    f  1  0  1  0
# 17:   2  1    g  1  0  1  0
# 18:   2  1    h  0  1  1  0
# 19:   2  1    i  0  1  1  0
# 20:   2  1    j  0  1  0  1
# 21:   3  2    a NA NA NA NA
# 22:   3  2    b NA NA NA NA
# 23:   3  2    c NA NA NA NA
# 24:   3  2    d NA NA NA NA
# 25:   3  2    e  1  0  1  0
# 26:   3  2    f  1  0  1  0
# 27:   3  2    g  1  0  1  0
# 28:   3  2    h  0  1  1  0
# 29:   3  2    i  0  1  1  0
# 30:   3  2    j  0  1  0  1
# 31:   4  2    a NA NA NA NA
# 32:   4  2    b NA NA NA NA
# 33:   4  2    c NA NA NA NA
# 34:   4  2    d NA NA NA NA
# 35:   4  2    e  1  0  1  0
# 36:   4  2    f  1  0  1  0
# 37:   4  2    g  1  0  1  0
# 38:   4  2    h  0  1  1  0
# 39:   4  2    i  0  1  1  0
# 40:   4  2    j  0  1  0  1
#     grp Yr name  a  b  c  d
```